# ¿como hacer 5 numeros aleatorios del 1 al 16 sin que se repitan en C#?

Tags: c#

como el titulo dice estoy intentando sacar 5 numeros sin que se repitan

`

```
        int min = 1;
        int max = 16;
        int num, num2, num3, num4, num5;

        Random rnd = new Random();
        num = (rnd.Next(min, max));
        num2 = (rnd.Next(min, max));
        num3 = (rnd.Next(min, max));
        num4 = (rnd.Next(min, max));
        num5 = (rnd.Next(min, max));`
```

los 5 numeros se generan bien pero simplemente no se me ocurre como hacer que no se repitan, intente hacerlo con IFs pero no lo logre

gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 2):

No es la solución más óptima por que funciona con la idea de:

- Generar una enumerable con los 16 enteros
- Ordenarlos de forma aleatoria
- Quedarnos con los primero 5 valores

---

```
Random rand = new Random();
var shuffled = Enumerable.Range(1, 16)
  .OrderBy(_ => rand.Next())
  .ToList()
  .Take(5);
```

Los dos primeros puntos eventualmente podrían ser costos si en vez de 16 valores posibles el número es mucho mayor.

Nota: Necesitarás agregar `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

1. Haces una función que te retorne una array de int's randoms, que reciba como argumentos el número mínimo, el máximo y la cantidad a generar

```
public static int[] GetRandoms(int min, int max, int cantidad)
```

2. Creas una array de largo igual a la cantidad de número que deseas para almacenar los resultados

```
int[] randoms = new int[cantidad];
```

3. Haces un for que itere la cantidad de números que deseas, **pero sin hacer i++**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cantidad;)
```

4. Creas un número random, y con un if preguntas si ya existe en el array. Si no existe lo agregas y ahora si haces el i++

```
int rand = rnd.Next(min, max);
if (!randoms.Contains(rand))
{
    randoms[i] = rand;
    i++;
}
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] randoms = GetRandoms(1, 16, 5);
    Console.WriteLine(randoms[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(randoms[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(randoms[2]);
    Console.WriteLine(randoms[3]);
    Console.WriteLine(randoms[4]);
}

public static int[] GetRandoms(int min, int max, int cantidad) 
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[] randoms = new int[cantidad];
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad;)
    {
        int rand = rnd.Next(min, max);
        if (!randoms.Contains(rand))
        {
            randoms[i] = rand;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return randoms;
}
```

Nota este código tiene un problema, Esto se debe cumplir max-min >= cantidad. Es decir la cantidad de número posibles debe estar dentro del rango adecuado, porque de lo contrario te queda un bucle infinito, ya que jamás encontraría la cantidad de número aleatorios necesarios. Te lo dejo para que lo perfecciones.